# Delete or hide applications in the Unity panel

Tags: unity, 20.04, panel

I want to delete or hide the items that are specified in the photo and the installed programs (Telegram, VLC, etc.) in the top panel of the Unity desktop (my operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS) !?
Can you advise me how I can do this?
https://uupload.ir/files/dnzi_up.png

Comment: Not quite sure about the two you have, but have qbittorrent and need to left click the icon and click on hide or quit(bottom choice).

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot be hidden! ‌
Later, when I try to exit, it leaves the whole program!

Comment: Try 'exit' on the icon in dash(side panel) first.  Just tried VLC, hide did not work, but quit did.